How much of the forward motion energy cost of a car is lost to bearings friction
If a car had perfect bearings with zero friction, how much less energy would it consume to keep moving forward, after cruise speed has been attained (not to accelerate to that velocity) than the current cars of today? What are the energy budget allotments (% energy used to overcome air resistance, friction, etc.)?

It's better measured as a torque loss. It is much more consistent over speed and throttle that way. And it varies greatly depending on the setup. There is no point to including aero in the calc. You want to look at the losses on a wheel dyno vs engine brake torque curve at various throttle levels. You want to look at the cost trade-offs among things you can actually control.

And again, the losses as a percentage of, say, typical engine torque needed to maintain highway speed will vary by about an order of magnitude.

The bearing losses on these two are rather different from each other. https://www.terex.com/docs/librariesprovider20/default-document-library/fdb7000.pdf?sfvrsn=de29fa7c_3  https://media.wired.com/photos/626857ff98bdedbbd2da0383/master/w_1920,c_limit/Wuling-Mini-EV-Gear.jpg

How many bearings are there that need to be considered?

Thing with mass attempting to move through a fluid while making contact with a rail and attempting to roll... Could describe balls in a bearing, but could also say the same about the whole car. Consider that if frictionless were possible, one could do away with the entire wagon.

Bearing losses are pretty low. In the 1950's, car companies would do demos of how good of mileage their cars could (theoretically) get. By using thin oil instead of grease in the wheel bearings (and balancing the wheels extremely carefully) friction was so low you could spin a wheel by hand, and it would keep spinning for around half an hour. The big difference in mileage wasn't prepping the car though. It was driving style. They'd slowly accelerate to about 45MPH, coast until they were down to around 5 MPH, and repeat. Their demos routinely got 50-60 MPG out of '50's land yachts.
